# Laravel notification Undefined variable: user

Tags: php, laravel

When I try to send email to logged user I get following error:

```
Undefined variable: user (View: ......\resources\views\mail\user\loggedIn.blade.php)
```

## Code

`Notification`

```
class UserLoggedIn extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
    protected $user;
    protected $ip;

    public function __construct($user, $ip)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->ip = $ip;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)->markdown('mail.user.loggedIn');
    }
    
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

`Email blade`

```
@component('mail::message')
  # Dear {{$user['name']}}
@endcomponent
```

`controller`

```
$user = User::where('email', $this->email)->first();
$user->notify((new UserLoggedIn($user, \Request::ip())));
```

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solved

Apparently we need to attach variables into view as well

```
return (new MailMessage)->markdown('mail.user.loggedIn', ['user' => $this->user, 'ip' => $this->ip]);
```

`['user' => $this->user, 'ip' => $this->ip]`